# How do I get the API to return a list of integers in Android?

Tags: java, android, api, int

Once again, I am new to coding and am trying to code an Android app for my robotics team. I have gotten pretty far, but I am stuck trying to return only the rank of some teams.

Here is my current onClick code

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    v.setEnabled(false);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnGetRanks:
            try {
                TextView textHeyo = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textGetRanks);
                textHeyo.setText(new EventRanking().execute(tba).get().toString());
            } catch (  ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
       //... more code not related to issue ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is my doInBackground thing (as I said, I am new)

```
public class EventRanking extends AsyncTask<TBA, Void, EventRankings> {

    protected EventRankings doInBackground(TBA... tbas) {

        try {
            EventRankings ourEventRankings = tbas[0].eventRequest.getRankings( "2019cada");
            EventRankings event = ourEventRankings;
            return ourEventRankings;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the entire list of things I can get with EventRequest

```
public class EventRequest {

    private DataRequest tba;

    /**
    * Creates an EventRequest object
    *
    * @param tba A {@link DataRequest} object with the appropriate auth key
    */
    public EventRequest(DataRequest tba) {
        this.tba = tba;
    }



    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return The {@link Event} object referenced by the given key
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Event getEvent(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey;
        return Deserializer.toEvent(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/simple</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return The {@link SimpleEvent} object referenced by the given key
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public SimpleEvent getSimpleEvent(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/simple";
        return Deserializer.toSimpleEvent(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/teams</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link Team} objects that competed in the given event.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Team[] getTeams(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/teams";
        return Deserializer.toTeamArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/teams/simple</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link SimpleTeam} objects that competed in the given event.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public SimpleTeam[] getSimpleTeams(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/teams/simple";
        return Deserializer.toSimpleTeamArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/teams/keys</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link Team} keys that competed in the given event.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public String[] getTeamKeys(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/teams/keys";
        return Deserializer.toStringArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/events/{year}</code>
     *
     * @param year Competition year (or season). Must be four digits.
     * @return A list of {@link Event} objects that occurred in a given year
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public Event[] getEvents(int year) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/events/" + year;
        return Deserializer.toEventArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/events/{year}/simple</code>
     *
     * @param year Competition year (or season). Must be four digits.
     * @return A list of {@link SimpleEvent} objects that occurred in a given year
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public SimpleEvent[] getSimpleEvents(int year) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/events/" + year + "/simple";
        return Deserializer.toSimpleEventArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/events/{year}/keys</code>
     *
     * @param year Competition year (or season). Must be four digits.
     * @return A list of {@link Event} keys that occurred in a given year
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String[] getEventKeys(int year) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + year + "/keys";
        return Deserializer.toStringArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/district_points</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of team rankings for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public EventDistrictPoints getDistrictPoints(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/district_points";
        return Deserializer.toEventDistrictPoints(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/alliances</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link EliminationAlliance}s for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public EliminationAlliance[] getAlliances(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/alliances";
        return Deserializer.toEliminationAllianceArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/oprs</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A set of {@link OPRs} (includeing OPR, DPR, and CCWM) for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public OPRs getOPRs(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/oprs";
        return Deserializer.toOPRs(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/rankings</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of team rankings for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public EventRankings getRankings(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/rankings";
        return Deserializer.toEventRankings(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/matches</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link Match}es for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Match[] getMatches(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/matches";
        return Deserializer.toMatchArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/matches/simple</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link SimpleMatch}es for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public SimpleMatch[] getSimpleMatches(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/matches/simple";
        return Deserializer.toSimpleMatchArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/matches/keys</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of match keys for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String[] getMatchKeys(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/matches/keys";
        return Deserializer.toStringArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }

    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/awards</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of {@link Award}s from the given the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Award[] getAwards(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/awards";
        return Deserializer.toAwardArray(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }
}
```

More specifically this is the one I am trying to get this one

```
    /**
     * Makes API requests with the subdirectory <code>/event/{eventKey}/rankings</code>
     *
     * @param eventKey TBA Event Key, e.g. <code>2016nytr</code>
     * @return A list of team rankings for the event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public EventRankings getRankings(String eventKey) throws IOException {
        String directory = "/event/" + eventKey + "/rankings";
        return Deserializer.toEventRankings(tba.getDataTBA(directory).getJson());
    }
```

This is the things you can get with EventRankings

```
    /**
     * The event rankings and tiebreaker information for an event
     */
    @Value
    public class EventRankings {

        /**
         * List of rankings at the event
         */
        public Ranking[] rankings;
        /**
         * List of year-specific values provided in the `sort_orders` array for each team.
         */
        public SortOrderInfo[] sort_order_info;

        /**
         * The Sort order of the rankings for a particular year
         */
        @Value
        public class SortOrderInfo {
            /**
             * Name of the field used in the <code>sort_order</code> array.
             */
            public String name;
            /**
             * Integer expressing the number of digits of precision in the number provided in sort_orders.
             */
            public int precision;

        }
```

This is what I am getting back, But I just want the team number and their rank

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok so you get an object `EventRankings` when you use `EventRankings getRankings(String eventKey)` and you want an object that has Team Numbers and Rank.

According to the image you shared:

- `EventRankings`
- has a collection of `Ranking`
- `Ranking` has an `int` `Rank`
- `Ranking` also has a String `team_key` (which I am going to guess is "team number"

You could do it a few ways:

## 1

Let's say you want that as some type of map *`Map<TeamNumber, Rank>`*

```
EventRankings eventRankings = getRankings("eventKey");

Map<String, Int> teamsRanked = new HashMap<>();
for(Ranking ranking : eventsRankings.rankings) {
    teamsRanked.put(ranking.teamKey, ranking.rank);
}
```

You can validate what you have then by printing it:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Int> entry : teamsRanked.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("TUT", entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Print a teams rank:

```
Log.d("TUT", "frc1323 is ranked: " + teamsRanked.get("frc1323"));
```

---

## 2

If you know that rankings are unique, you could also have your map the other way around:

```
Map<String, Int> rankedTeams = new HashMap<>();
for(Ranking ranking : eventsRankings.rankings) {
    rankedTeams.put(ranking.rank, ranking.teamKey);
}
```

And then you can get a team based on rank, i.e. print the top 3:

```
Log.d("TUT", "Ranked #1 is: " + rankedTeams.get(1));
Log.d("TUT", "Ranked #2 is: " + rankedTeams.get(2));
Log.d("TUT", "Ranked #3 is: " + rankedTeams.get(3));
```

---

## 3

Or finally if you don't want to easily lookup by rank or name, you could have a List of new objects, perhaps `List<Result>`.

```
class Result {

   private final String teamName;
   private final int rank;

   public Result(String teamName, int rank) {
       this.teamName = teamName;
       this.rank = rank;
   }

   public String getTeamName() {
       return teamName;
   }

   public int getRank() {
       return rank;
   }
}

List<Result> results = new HashMap<>();
for(Ranking ranking : eventsRankings.rankings) {
    results.add(new Result(ranking.teamKey, ranking.rank));
}
```

And print each result:

```
for(Result result : results) {
    Log.d("TUT", result.getTeamName() + " : " + result.getRank());
}
```

---

Taken from:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, can I just ask for the first and second one, where does the code go? Like which part I guess. Sorry! I am very new to this

Comment: inside `doInBackground` of the `ASyncTask` you would change it to return a different type of object (the 3rd parameter in the type args `<>` would change from `EventRankings` to whatever you have chosen.)

Comment: I am getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.scoutingapp4.RankingsFragment.onClick(RankingsFragment.java:50)

Comment: so what's line 50? Seems like your ASyncTask might now be returning `null`. I answered your question - you may need to mark this answered and and open a question

Comment: @Cail if this answered your question, please mark it as answered